# How to add computed variable to the wagtail StructBlock template context?

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I want to compute some `custom` variable based on the other block values in the `StructBlock` and add this `custom` variable to the template context. Essentially I should be able to use this computed variable in the `StructBlock` template like so `{{ value.custom }}`.

Here's my `StructBlock`:

```
class BaseBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    bool_fld = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, default=False)

    def get_context(self, *a, **kw):
        ctx = super().get_context(*a, **kw)
        ctx['custom'] = 1 if self.bool_fld else 0
        return ctx
```

And the error:

> 'BaseBlock' object has no attribute 'bool_fld'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `get_context` method on block objects receives the block value as its first argument - in the case of `StructBlock`, this is a dict-like object whose fields can be accessed as `value['some_field']`.

```
class BaseBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    bool_fld = blocks.BooleanBlock(required=False, default=False)

    def get_context(self, value, parent_context=None):
        ctx = super().get_context(value, parent_context=parent_context)
        ctx['custom'] = 1 if value['bool_fld'] else 0
        return ctx
```

See also the `get_context` example at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering.

`self.bool_fld` won't work here, because `Block` instances do not hold values themselves - they just act as converters between different data representations. (If you've worked with Django form field objects like `forms.CharField`, blocks are very similar; both block objects and form field objects know how to render values passed to them as form fields, but they don't hold on to those values.)

Comment: Thanks, eventually I've figured that I can use `ctx['value']['bool_fld']`, but your method seems much cleaner. I don't think that I've seen what `get_context` is receiving in the `block` objects in the docs, so it would be nice to have it there. Perhaps I should contribute to `wagtail` with git PR by re-posting your answers :)